# Magento - Product pages not loading

Tags: php, magento

This was what the *Magento* logging came back with:

Log:

> 2014-04-28T22:10:23+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in /chroot/home/buggslyc/buggsly.com/html/app/design/frontend/default/milano/template/catalog/product/list.phtml on line 256
>   2014-04-28T22:10:23+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: **backImg** in /chroot/home/buggslyc/buggsly.com/html/app/design/frontend/default/milano/template/catalog/product/list.phtml on line 225
>   2014-04-28T22:10:23+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: **backImg** in /chroot/home/buggslyc/buggsly.com/html/app/design/frontend/default/milano/template/catalog/product/list.phtml on line 225
>   2014-04-28T22:10:23+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: **backImg** in /chroot/home/buggslyc/buggsly.com/html/app/design/frontend/default/milano/template/catalog/product/list.phtml on line 226
>   2014-04-28T22:10:23+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: **backImg** in /chroot/home/buggslyc/buggsly.com/html/app/design/frontend/default/milano/template/catalog/product/list.phtml on line 226
>   2014-04-28T22:10:23+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in /chroot/home/buggslyc/buggsly.com/html/app/design/frontend/default/milano/template/catalog/product/list.phtml on line 256

Line 256 reads:

```
<h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'), $length = $trimSize, $etc = '...', $remainder = '', $breakWords = true); ?></a></h2>
```

Line 225 reads:

```
<?php if($backImg != 'null' && $backImg): ?><img src="<?php echo $backImg ?>" class="hover-image" width="<?php echo $imgSize ?>" height="<?php echo $imgHeight ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /><?php endif; ?>
```

Line 226 reads:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($imgSize, $imgHeight) ?>" <?php if($backImg != 'null' && $backImg): ?>class="hover-main-image" <?php endif; ?> width="<?php echo $imgSize ?>" height="<?php echo $imgHeight ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

just use the function like this if passing default values:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($productName,40); ?>
```

no need to provide default arguments.
look at the definition of the function:

```
 public function truncate($string, $length = 80, $etc = '...', &$remainder = '', $breakWords = true)
```

Answer (score -1):

These are not valid inputs for a function:

```
$length = $trimSize, $etc = '...', $remainder = '', $breakWords = true
```

Which can be seen on line 256 here:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'), $length = $trimSize, $etc = '...', $remainder = '', $breakWords = true); ?>
```

It should be:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(),'name'),$trimSize,'...','',true); ?>
```